# Probability that a game is worth playing

Tags: probability

At a fairground you see a sign for a game: “Win £5 - only 50p a go!”. You
decide to watch the game a few times to decide whether it’s worth playing.
You observe 18 people playing the game, and 2 of them win. Calculate the
probability that the game is worth playing based on this information.

How would I go about solving this? I would assume that the answer>50%, since the game loses money in the example

Comment: Wouldn't it just be P = desirable outcome/total outcomes, so 2/18 = 1/9?

Comment: no, since the desirable outcomes are worth more than the undesirable ones

Comment: This is how I would start: Let the probability of winning be $p$. Now, in order for the game to be worth playing, we want the expected winnings to be positive. You win 4.5 pounds with probability $p$, and you lose 0.5 pounds with probability $1-p$, so the expected winnings is
$$
4.5p + (1-p)(-0.5)
$$
We want this to be $>0$, so solving for $p$ yields the condition $p>\frac{1}{10}$. Now, let's look at the trials and successes. Let $X$ be the event "2 successes out of 18 trials". Now we are interested in calculating the probability
$$
P(p>\frac{1}{10}| X)
$$

Comment: If you continue with the same approach that I started on the previous comment, you will quickly see that the prior distribution for $p$ is required. What is the distribution of $p$, when we look at all the fairground games in the world? Would it be reasonable to assume $p\sim \text{Uniform}[0,1]$ ?